# HTTP status codes in spring for android

Tags: android, spring, rest

Hi I want to take the HTTP status codes when something goes wrong with the network.

I use try catch but I can only take the message. How I can take only the codes.

Also something else. There is any event called automatically if something go wrong? canI can override it?

This is my code into asyncTask

```
 protected HistoricalWeatherResponse doInBackground(String... params) {
        HistoricalWeatherResponse response = new HistoricalWeatherResponse();
        try {
            HttpHeaders requestHeaders = new HttpHeaders();

            List<MediaType> acceptableMedia = new ArrayList<MediaType>();
            acceptableMedia.add(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);

            requestHeaders.setAccept(acceptableMedia);

            HttpEntity<?> requestEntity = new HttpEntity<Object>(requestHeaders);

            RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
            restTemplate.getMessageConverters().add(new MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter());

            ResponseEntity<HistoricalWeatherResponse> responseEntity = restTemplate.exchange("http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/history/city?q="+params[0]+"&cnt=2", HttpMethod.GET, requestEntity, HistoricalWeatherResponse.class);

            response = responseEntity.getBody();

            response.setSuccess(true);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            response.setError(e);
            response.setSuccess(false);
            Log.d("LEE",e.getMessage());
        }

        return response;
    }
```

Thanks!

Comment: What class are you using for performing network operations?

Comment: I use restTemplate (see the example I add above). I want in catch to get the status code. in order to recognize the error by myself.

Comment: On the ResponseEntity class there is a method called getStatusCode() which returns the HttpStatus enum which has methods for dealing with the status codes.                       

http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/http/ResponseEntity.html#getStatusCode--

http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/http/HttpStatus.html